# Playing around with my cache app and I expect the timestamp to stay on the screen but it disappears after postback

Tags: c#, webforms

.Net 4.8

Why doesn't the timestamp persist on my server side label control after I cache the listbox? I wouldn't expect it to update but I do expect it to be there and not disappear.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CacheApp.aspx.cs" Inherits="CachePractice.CacheApp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Cache App, Get it?</h1>
    </div>
    <div>

        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelCurrentTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add value to cache" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Remove cache" OnClick="Button2_Click" /><br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CachePractice
{
    public partial class CacheApp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Cache["WeekData"] != null)
            {
                ListBox1.DataSource = Cache["WeekData"];
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                ListBox1.DataSource = null;
                ListBox1.DataBind();

                LabelCurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Sunday");
            list.Add("Monday");
            list.Add("Tuesday");
            list.Add("Wednesday");
            list.Add("Thursday");
            list.Add("Friday");
            list.Add("Saturday");
            Cache["WeekData"] = list;
        }
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cache.Remove("WeekData");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: l'm just caching the listbox but i thought the other server-side controls would persist their values autumatically because of "runat=server"

Comment: `runat="server"` makes them server side controls, but [ViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448(v=vs.100)) is what causes those other controls to keep their value between postbacks. Do you possibly have ViewState turned off, perhaps in the web.config file? The [Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.cache?view=netframework-4.8) property of the page is what you're using to cache your `List<string>`.

Comment: Not that i know of, i just used the standard web forms template in vs 2022

Comment: So this is a brand new project? Why do a brand new Web Forms app in 2022? Is there some reason you're unable to use ASP.NET Core?

Comment: If you hit Button1 multiple times, does the value start persisting? The button click handlers are going to run after the Page_Load event.

Comment: @mason you're right, it is persisting. I was hitting the tab for the page which isn't a postback. sorry for confusion.

Comment: if you want to put that as an answer, i'll mark it

Comment: No, I don't really think it's useful to others. If you feel like it, you can put it in an answer yourself.